# Is there a go linter that can find "nil pointer dereference" potential panic?

Tags: go

Here is simple example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type A struct {
    Name *string
}

type B struct {
    A *A
}

func main() {
    deref(&B{})
}

func deref(b *B) {
    fmt.Println(*b.A.Name) // panic: nil pointer dereference
}
```

I'm looking for a solution that can find this type of situations.
There is a "nillness check" in Jetbrains Goland but it doesn't inspect this issue.

Comment: Is it this specific case you're concerned about, or you just want the most comprehensive nil pointer linter available?

Comment: A linter can only find the most obvious cases, so this is usually covered sufficiently by basic testing.

Answer (score 7):

I asked your question somewhere else [1], and got this response:

> Detecting all `nil` pointer dereferences is impossible without false positives,
> and we don't generally tolerate false positives. It would also be fairly
> expensive to compute.
>
> Detecting trivial `nil` pointer dereferences like this one isn't worth it,
> because even with minor additions to the code they would no longer be easy to
> detect.
>
> We do have [SA5011](https://staticcheck.io/docs/checks#SA5011) which flags a
> specific kind of potential `nil` pointer dereference, though this wouldn't help
> with your example.

1. https://github.com/dominikh/go-tools/issues/1035